# Symfony2 EasyAdmin exception in getting list view

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony2-easyadmin

I have an entity `Sessions` where the PK is also the FK referencing a `User` table. In the EasyAdmin list view page for `Sessions`, I'm getting a Symfony runtime exception (Twig_Error_Runtime):

`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Paginating an entity with foreign key as identifier only works when using the Output Walkers. Call Paginator#setUseOutputWalkers(true) before iterating the paginator.").`

The `Sessions` table is like this:

`student (FK, PK) | mentor_id (FK) | start | end`

Both student and mentor_id are FKs to the `User` table

Comment: I'm having this same problem. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No I didn't. I soon realized I don't need the student to be both FK and PK so I went with a revised design. I also disabled the new and edit views for this entity because I don't need it. Everything works ok.

Comment: I couldn't trace the source of the problem either, sorry. It seems nobody faced this problem before or knows why this is happening.